# Inherit a template class with an inner class and access the inner class within the inherited class

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have a template class "BinaryHeap" which also declares a public class "Item" within itself.

Now I want to extend the BinaryHeap with a hash for element lookup and therefore inherited it. I called it "HashedBinaryHeap", which should use the same Item class like BinaryHeap does.

The stub looks like this:

```
template<class T>
class BinaryHeap {
public:
    class Item {...};
    ...
    void appendItem(const Item & item);
    ...
};

template<class T>
class HashedBinaryHeap : public BinaryHeap<T> {
public:
    ...
    void appendItem(const Item & item);
    ...
};
```

The problem now is, when I try to access the Item class within HashedBinaryHeap like I do in the `appendItem()` method, I get some compiler errors.

When I write it like above or with the <T>:

```
void appendItem(const Item & item);
void appendItem(const Item<T> & item);
```

I get:

```
ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'Item' with no type
```

When I do one of:

```
void appendItem(const HashedBinaryHeap::Item & item);
void appendItem(const HashedBinaryHeap<T>::Item & item);
```

I get:

```
expected unqualified-id before '&' token
```

So how can I 'access' the class Item within HashedBinaryHeap? What am I misunderstanding?

(Maybe this isn't something template class related problem, but I know template classes are confusing a lot of C++ beginners, and I still don't dare calling myself something else... Please get me out. :))

Thanks in advance!

Comment: BinaryHeap<T>::Item or typename BinaryHeap<T>::Item?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? I tried putting `typedef typename BinaryHeap<T>::Item Item` in the declarations top, but it did'n compile: `typename BinaryHeap<T>::Item is not a template`

Comment: void appendItem(const typename BinaryHeap<T>::Item & item); is working for me

Comment: void appendItem(const typename HashedBinaryHeap<T>::Item & item); is also good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, solved it!

```
void appendItem(const typename HashedBinaryHeap<T>::Item & item);
```

This did the trick - I didn't know about typename...